# Python turtle checkerboard each line starts 30 pixels to the right

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a checkerboard. I have this code to make a checker board -- it works but the rows don't match up.  How do I get each row to start at the beginning e.g. go backward 150?  I have tried one row go backward 150 and then the second back 120.

```
import turtle
turtle.speed(0)

def go_to_start():
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pd()

def colour():
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    for j in range(5):
        turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range (4):
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.pd()



def first_row():
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(180)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(270)
    turtle.pd()



def second_row():
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(150)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.right(270)
    turtle.pd()


go_to_start()


for j in range (5):
    for i in range (5):
        colour()
    second_row()
    first_row()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to go back the same distance for every row of the table, this is not correct. You need to implement some logic to go back the right amount for each row. As an example, you could replace the first_row, second_row, and for loop with:

```
def reset():
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(300)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(270)
    turtle.pd()


for j in range (5):
    for i in range (5):
        colour()
    #if the row is even, then go forward 30
    if j %2 == 0:
        turtle.forward(30)
    #if the row is odd, then go backward 30
    else:
        turtle.backward(30)
    reset()
```

Comment: Great stuffthank you that is great and much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've a couple of suggestions for making your program much simpler and much faster.  First, checkerboards are a perfect opportunity to ***stamp*** instead of ***draw***.  Second, stop thinking left-to-right but instead think bidirectionally:

```
import turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
SQUARE_SIZE = 30

turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

distance = 2 * SQUARE_SIZE

for j in range(8):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(distance)

    # if row is odd, go forward one square else go backward one square
    turtle.forward(SQUARE_SIZE if j % 2 else -SQUARE_SIZE)

    distance = -distance

    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - SQUARE_SIZE)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.done()
```

[image]